# System.out.println("Console message") does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I tried printing messages using the System.out.println("Console message") but the messages are not getting printed in the console. Any specific reasons for this? How to print the console messages then?

i can see another window named DDMS. what is the use of it?

Please help

Regards,
Bunty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Log.d("Title", "Message");` instead of console and you can see result in **logcat** window

Answer (score 1):

the standard output  goes automatically to logcat
you can access it using the   "adb logcat" command

or  using  the logcat view in eclipse

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Why is DDMS console used for? Is it for logging messages?

Comment: ddms  is the  Dalvik Debug Monitor Server there is a special view for it in eclipse it is used  for exteded emulator control for example you can   simulate  a sms message or   a call

Answer (score 1):

Here's some [reading material](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for you.

Comment: About link only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259

Answer (score 1):

You must first search then go to ask questions, it's android developer link for tutorial about it :

- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html